# What is the Time Complexity of below implementation of Recursive Level Order Traversal using Map and Vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, vector, stl

Here is my own implementation of Level Order Traversal using Map and Vector in C++. The algorithm goes this way :

1. Create a Binary Search Tree using recursion
2. Create a Hash Map of levels and the nodes present in each level using recursion
3. Traverse the HashMap for each and every key and print the elements of vector associated with the key

Since I am not good at STL, I have trouble finding the exact Time and Space complexity.

```
> // Level Order Traversal using Map and Vector
> // Time Complexity = ;
> // Space Complexity = ;
>
>      #include<iostream>
>      #include<map>
>      #include<vector>
>     
>     using namespace std;
>     
>     struct node
>     {
>       struct node *left;
>       int data;
>       struct node *right;
>     };
>     
>     struct node *newNode(int a)
>     {
>       struct node *Temp = new struct node();
>     
>       Temp->left = NULL;
>       Temp->data = a;
>       Temp->right = NULL;
>     
>       return Temp;
>     }
>     
>     void createNode(struct node **root,int x)
>     {
>       if(*root!=NULL)
>       {
>           if(x < (*root)->data)
>               createNode(&(*root)->left,x);
>           else
>               createNode(&(*root)->right,x);
>       }
>       else
>           *root = newNode(x);
>     }
>     
>     void _getLEVEL(struct node *root,int level,int *ML,map<int,vector<int>> &LevelMap)
>     {
>       if(root==NULL)
>           return;
>     
>       if(level > *ML)
>           *ML = level;
>       LevelMap[*ML].push_back(root->data);
>       _getLEVEL(root->left,level+1,ML,LevelMap);
>       *ML=0;
>       _getLEVEL(root->right,level+1,ML,LevelMap);
>     
>     }
>     
>     void _printLevel(map<int,vector<int>> &LevelMap)
>     {
>       map<int,vector<int>>::iterator i;
>     
>       for(i=LevelMap.begin() ; i!=LevelMap.end() ; i++)
>       {
>           cout<<"Level "<<i->first<<" : ";
>           for(int j=0 ; j<=i->second.size()-1; j++)
>               cout<<i->second[j]<<" ";
>           cout<<endl;
>       }
>     
>     }
>     
>     void printTree_LEVELORDER(struct node *root)
>     {
>       int MaxLevel = 0;
>       map<int,vector<int>> LevelMap;
>       _getLEVEL(root,0,&MaxLevel,LevelMap);
>       _printLevel(LevelMap);
>     }
>     
>     int main()
>     {
>       int arr[] = {6,3,8,2,9,7,10};
>       int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
>     
>       struct node *Tree=NULL;
>     
>       for(int i=0 ; i<=n-1 ; i++)
>           createNode(&Tree,arr[i]);
>     
>       cout<<"The Level Order Traversal is : "<<endl;
>       printTree_LEVELORDER(Tree);
>       cout<<endl;
>     
>       cin.get();
>       return 0;
>     }
```

Comment: Did you try or do you have nothing? Btw. `void main()` is wrong, and you don't delete all allocated memory here.

Comment: Yes.. It is working for me. I have corrected void main() part. Why is that wrong?

Comment: `Yes.. It is working for me` I meant if you tried to get the complexity, and what your guess is. I won't do your homework just like that. About void main: It's wrong because the C++ standard says that it is wrong, that's all.

Comment: @deviantfan.. for time being lets focus on complexity part. Not on memory leaks.

Comment: @deviantfan.. dude I am working in a company. I dont have homeworks.. These days I am learning DSA by myself thats all.. .. no need to think 'deviant'

Comment: This is what my output from Visual Studio :

The Level Order Traversal is :
Level 0 : 6
Level 1 : 3 8
Level 2 : 2 7 9
Level 3 : 10

Comment: ...I'm asking one last time: Did you try [to calculate the complexity, manually]? It doesn't matter if it is school, work, hobby or anything else, it's your task. Asking is fine, but not "do this because I'm to lazy".. And I'm not interested in the output of VS.

Comment: Step 1 = O(n) - we are cerating n nodes and thus ? 
Step 2 = O(logn) - since it is a map? thats what I learnt in cplusplusreference
Step 3 = O(n) - since we are traversing the map and the elements of the node single time 
**bold** Overall Time Complexity = O(n) (since n is dominating)
Space for Tree = O(n)
Space for Map = How to calculate this? I am stuck since this is a 'map of vectors' My wild guess is O(n)
**bold** Overall Space complexity = O(n)

Comment: And another question, what kind of time complexity do you want? Worst possible case, best case, average?

Comment: Refer my above comment for the guess I have made.
As it usually goes, I want the Worst Case complexity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm skipping the `O(1)` stuff.

In main, first `createNode` is called n times. `createNode` itself searches the tree for a insert position, up to each level: `log(n)`. => `O(n*log(n))`

Then, in `printTree_LEVELORDER`, `_getLEVEL` and `_printLevel` are called.

`_getLEVEL` first: The whole tree is traversed, and for each tree node, you make an entry in one of the vectors (in the map). As there are n nodes, in all vectors together there will be n entries as soon as the function finished (just split up among several vectors in the map) => `O(n)`

And then `_printLevel` prints all elements of all vectors in the map. Normally O(n*m), but as we know there are only `O(n)` elements in total, it's `O(n)` too.

`O(n*log(n)) + O(n) + O(n) = O(n*log(n))` is the final worst-case time complexity.

Space if `O(n)`: A array with n elements, and exactly
one tree node and one map vector element for each.

Comment: Comment 7 was motivating and I was indeed correct with my own calculation of Space Complexity. Thanks.

Comment: How to improve the Time Complexity to O(n)? Can you suggest tweaks?